# Android ExifInterface Orientation Attribute is always 0

Tags: android, image, android-intent, orientation, exif

I would like to force all images captured from a camera intent to be oriented in landscape. I am testing this on a Moto X Pure Ed and the EXIF orientation attribute is 0 for both portrait and landscape photos. The image is correctly displayed but I want to intervene so that the orientation will always be in landscape.

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to either modify the image file or instruct the camera app to shoot in landscape. I have also tried changing the exif attribute directly using `setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));`

Any suggestions or help that this is even possible is appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here, any solution?